# Rolling difference of date column with groupby in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
foo = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data={'id': {0: '1',
  1: '1',
  2: '1',
  3: '2',
  4: '2'},
 'session': {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2},
 'start_time': {0: Timestamp('2021-09-02 19:49:19'),
  1: Timestamp('2021-09-16 10:54:21'),
  2: Timestamp('2021-07-12 17:11:54'),
  3: Timestamp('2021-03-02 01:53:22'),
  4: Timestamp('2021-01-09 11:38:35')}})
```

I would like to add a new column to `foo`, called `diff_start_time`, which would be the difference of the `start_time` column of the current `session` from the previous one, grouped by `id`. I would like the difference to be in `hours`.

How could I do that in python ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) with [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
foo['diff_start_time'] = foo.groupby('id')['start_time'].diff().dt.total_seconds().div(3600)
print (foo)

  id  session          start_time  diff_start_time
0  1        3 2021-09-02 19:49:19              NaN
1  1        2 2021-09-16 10:54:21       327.083889
2  1        1 2021-07-12 17:11:54     -1577.707500
3  2        1 2021-03-02 01:53:22              NaN
4  2        2 2021-01-09 11:38:35     -1238.246389
```

If necessary sorting first by `id, session`:

```
foo = foo.sort_values(['id','session'])
foo['diff_start_time'] = foo.groupby('id')['start_time'].diff().dt.total_seconds().div(3600)
print (foo)

  id  session          start_time  diff_start_time
2  1        1 2021-07-12 17:11:54              NaN
1  1        2 2021-09-16 10:54:21      1577.707500
0  1        3 2021-09-02 19:49:19      -327.083889
3  2        1 2021-03-02 01:53:22              NaN
4  2        2 2021-01-09 11:38:35     -1238.246389
```

Comment: Just posted around the same time :-)

Comment: @SeaBean - Ya, only difference is `div`, what is same like `/`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) + [`dt.total_seconds()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) to get the total number of seconds in difference, then divide by 3600 to get the differences in hours.

```
df_out = foo.sort_values(['id', 'session'])
df_out['diff_start_time'] = df_out.groupby('id')['start_time'].diff().dt.total_seconds() / 3600
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

  id  session          start_time  diff_start_time
2  1        1 2021-07-12 17:11:54              NaN
1  1        2 2021-09-16 10:54:21      1577.707500
0  1        3 2021-09-02 19:49:19      -327.083889
3  2        1 2021-03-02 01:53:22              NaN
4  2        2 2021-01-09 11:38:35     -1238.246389
```